# AdminUtils.createTopic API throws kafka.admin.AdminOperationException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent 3.0.1 platform on windows. I followed installation guide and developer guide to do all installation and develop my Topology.

I started Zookeeper, then Kafka server and try to run my topology. But getting below error on Kafka server. Even if I create topic manually and run the topology I see same error.

```
INFO Topic creation {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[0]}} (kafka.admin.AdminUtils$)
[2016-09-21 17:20:08,807] INFO [KafkaApi-0] Auto creation of topic Text4 with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2016-09-21 17:20:09,436] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request {group_id=my-first-streams-application1} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
  at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:117)
  at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:403)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis.kafka$server$KafkaApis$$createTopic(KafkaApis.scala:629)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis.kafka$server$KafkaApis$$createGroupMetadataTopic(KafkaApis.scala:651)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$getOrCreateGroupMetadataTopic$1.apply(KafkaApis.scala:657)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$getOrCreateGroupMetadataTopic$1.apply(KafkaApis.scala:657)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis.getOrCreateGroupMetadataTopic(KafkaApis.scala:657)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleGroupCoordinatorRequest(KafkaApis.scala:818)
  at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:86)
  at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:60)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And my topology code is below:

```java
public class MetricTopology implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("getStreamsConfig")
    private Properties properties;

    // Method to build topology.
    public void buildTopology() {
        System.out.println("MetricTopology.buildTopology()");
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        // add the source processor node that takes Kafka topic "Text4" as input
        builder.addSource("Source", "Text4")
            // add the Metricsprocessor node which takes the source processor as its upstream processor
            .addProcessor("Process", () -> new MetricsProcessor(), "Source");
        // Building Stream.
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, properties);
        streams.start();
    }

    // Called after all properties are set.
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        buildTopology();
    }

}
```

Below are the Properties which I am using which is part of different java source file.

```java
Properties settings = new Properties();
// Set a few key parameters. This properties will be picked from property file.
settings.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-first-streams-application1");
settings.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
settings.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
settings.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
settings.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
settings.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, "1");
```

Comment: And I am getting below error on running my topology on application side                                  [ StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 30 : {Text4=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

Answer (score 1):

```
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
```

In order to create a topic with replication factor 3, you need at least 3 running brokers.